# Vue.js отслеживание клика вне элемента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть следующая разметка:

```
<p class="row" @dblclick="changingPrice" >
    <span v-if="isChangingPrice">
        <input type="text" v-model="currentPrice" @change="changePrice" @keyup.enter="changingPrice">
    </span>
    <span v-else>{{currentPrice}} руб</span>
</p>
```

По умолчанию показывается цена товара. При двойном клике инициализируется `changingPrice`, который меняет переменную `isChangingPrice = !isChangingPrice`.

Таким образом, после двойного клика, я получаю возможность редактирования данного поля.

Каким образом я могу менять переменную `isChangingPrice` по клику ВНЕ input'a?

Comment: повесить слушатель на событие? вопрос только какое вам нужно

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать кастомную директиву:

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
    bind(el, binding) {
        el.addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation());
        document.body.addEventListener('click', binding.value);
    },
    unbind(el, binding) {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', binding.value);
    }
});
```

Использование:

```
<div v-click-outside="close">
```

Только в этом примере значением может быть только функция.